# Unable to convert YY-mm generated by zoo package , to Date format in R

Tags: r, date, na

I have a Date column (e.g. 1985-01) which I generated by combining two different columns with zoo package (month and year) as follow : `my_data$Date<-as.Date(as.yearmon(paste(my_data$year, my_data$month), "%Y %m"))`.

From this, I get the column I want but class`(my_data$Date)` gives me `"factor"`.

I have tried the following in order to convert it to Date format (because I want to display on year on my ggplot axis) but with no success.

```
as.Date(t$Date,format="%y-%m")
```

or

```
as.Date(t$Date, format = "%Y-%m")
```

or

```
format(as.Date(my_data$Date, format="%Y-%m"))
```

or

```
transform(my_data, Date = as.Date(Date))
```

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: YOu may need to dput the example.  From the code, it seems that you converted to `Date` class

Comment: I am trying to convert my factor column generated by zoo to Date. Apologies, what is dput?

Comment: Try `?dput` - providing sample data is essential here!